# How can we get the list of bluetooth enabled devices in Xamarin forms application?

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have followed the following URL : https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle
But I didn't get that much clarity, is there anyway to get he solution a bit easily ? I just need the list of devices and RSSI....

Comment: Did you got a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using plugin from https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le. To scan the list of devices:

```
adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s,a) => deviceList.Add(a.Device);
await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
```

There is also a sample app in the plugin source code for reference.